# How can I pair my Apple keyboard and mouse to multiple Macbooks Pro?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I would like to use my Apple wireless keyboard and mouse with my work and personal Macbook without having to pair them every time. Is there a simple way to pair with multiple Macbooks and switch between them?

Answer (score 0):

You can pair several but they tend to auto pair with the first beacon and not the computer you want.

Usually you can force a pair from the current machine but I’d recommend getting a device that has a button to have the keyboard choose which Bluetooth module to pair or get a KVM.